# ExpressionEngine API - get channel entries to show on different site

Tags: channel-entries-api

I have a news on my EE site, it's http.
Then i have another site that run on https.
I want to show my news entries on my https site, remembering that https cannot iframing http page, i think i can use API to achive this.

My question is:
can i use API?
if yes, how to implement it?
if no, can you give me options to achive my goal?

Thanks,
Best Regards,
.mafaik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try creating an RSS feed on the news site. It's fairly easy to setup an XML template and build it out using the standard RSS format, which you can find easily with a Google search.

After you have an RSS template established, you can use the [Feed Parser](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/feed_parser) add-on on the other site to read and display the RSS feed contents.